# Check ID across tables using Django Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently trying to count user activity, but will only count it two days after they first sign up. Since I'm going to be postprocessing the data, I'd like to have it return a Django QuerySet.

The only fields that are relevant are the following:

```
User
user_id, install_time

Activity
user_id, date, [list of activities]
```

While I have hacked together a solution, it is extremely inefficient ( O(n²) ), since I have to match the `user_id`s individually in consecutive `for`loops.

As it stands, `ForeignKey` fields would not fit in my models. I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships); however, I can't find a way that will only return a QuerySet where `user_id`s match and `date > install_time + datetime.timedelta(2)`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Here's my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    install_time = models.DateTimeField()

class Activity(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    # Misc activity-related fields
```

Comment: You have already asked an almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523672/check-id-across-tables-using-django-queryset. That's bad!

Comment: @rubik Thanks for pointing that out! I accidentally submitted the question earlier when I was tagging, but stopped the page redirect, so I was unaware I double posted. This one is more thorough, though, so I have deleted the other question.

Comment: why does matching user_ids from one sequence to another make it n^2 ?

Comment: @TillBackhaus I was using two dict lists returned by `.values().annotate(fields)`, so I had to iterate over each dict before storing the ones that matched up. Not saying it was the best choice; it was just a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your models aren't using explicit joins, you can't use field `F` objects as Chris Pratt suggested.

If you are unable to modify your schema, I can see two other options that still leverage some of the django ORM, but require you to write SQL queries/fragments.

I'm assuming postgresql and completely guessing at the db schema that django might from your models that you've said aren't correctly named.

[`QuerySet.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)
E.g.:

```
activity_set = Activity.objects.extra(
  tables=['myapp_user'],
  where=[
    "myapp_activity.user_id=myapp_user.user_id",
    "myapp_activity.date - myapp_user.install_time > '2 days'"
    ])
```

Using `extra` can be awkward, you can check the sql it's producing by `str(activity_set.query)`.

Alternatively, you could use the [`Manager.raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) and hand craft the query entirely. E.g.:

```
activity_set = Activity.objects.raw("""
 SELECT
   myapp_activity.* from myapp_activity, myapp_user
 WHERE 
   myapp_activity.user_id=myapp_user.user_id
   and myapp_activity.date - myapp_user.install_time > '2 days'
""")
```

Comment: Thanks, the `QuerySet.extra` was just what I was looking for. For future reference, though, `Manager.raw` returns a `RawQuerySet` which has extremely diminished functionality wrt `QuerySet`'s `.filter()`, `.values()`, and similar functions.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your models, it's impossible to give you any clear direction, but Django's query API supports a traversal pattern.

You could potentially do something like:

```
from django.db.models import F

Activity.objects.filter(date__gt=F('user__install_time')+timedelta(2))
```

**UPDATE (based on edit)**

The way you have your models set up is inefficient and won't allow you to take advantage of code like the above. In particular, you should have a foreign key to `User` on `Activity`.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

The use of `user_id` on `User` is probably not the best choice either. Even though you don't specify it directly (or rather I guess *because* you don't specify it directly), Django automatically adds an `id` field to your model that is a primary key on your table. So your model is *actually*:

```
 class User(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField()
     user_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
     install_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Having both `id` and `user_id` on your model is confusing. If `user_id` is meant to be akin to a username, renamed it it to `username`. Otherwise, you probably don't even need it.

Finally, it's odd that you're actually defining a `User` class in the first place. If you ever intend to use Django's `auth` package for authentication and user management, you're going to have *huge* problems (which means you should *never* really define your own `User` ever, just in case). If you need to add extra fields to the built-in `User`, you can do that with a profile model. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Comment: It's not actually named `User`, and I'm working off a legacy db; otherwise, I'd have already carried out your suggestions. Still, this is a great signpost for future users.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the quick response; it didn't get me all the way there, but it's close enough to avoid the terrible runtime I had before.